# How to make scroll div in Angular Dialog window

Tags: css, html

I want to do something like a chart in a dialog. The problem is that the graph is long and the dialog box has only 800 px. I am trying to do a scroll at the bottom which would support a div and move it to the left and right, but instead of creating a graph in one line css creates a next line in the dialog box and adds a scroll on the right.

code :

```
<mat-dialog-content>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="columns" *ngFor="let obj of getArray(); let i = index"
                     index="{{i}}" value="{{obj}}"></div>
    </div>
  </mat-dialog-content>
```

css:

```
columns {
  display: inline-block;

}

.table {
  min-height: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Problem resolved, i used white-space: nowrap;

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to your css `max-height` and when your content height more than div haight your `scroll-x` must work